# Logging service SOAP request and response

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, logging, soap

I am trying to log the soap request and response messages of a service in C#. I have a ready made soap extension which does all this, however I am having trouble adding it to the service method.

Since I have a service reference added in my VS project and not a web service reference, when i check the reference file for this service, I don't see the method which is doing the invoking of the remote service. All the examples I saw were of adding to a web service, which has a different reference format.

How can I log the soap messages in this case?

Answer (score 13):

Soap extension is only for using ASMX based service or client = Add web reference. Once you used Add service reference you are using WCF client API instead and you cannot use Soap extension. You must create [message inspector instead](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx).

If you need message logging only for debugging purpose you can use built in [WCF message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx).

Comment: ur answer saved me lot a time.
The info that "Soap extension is only for using ASMX based service or client = Add web reference" is not easy to find on internet.. Thanks alot once again

Answer (score 2):

There is an another way to see XML SOAP - [**custom MessageEncoder**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-custom-text-encoder). The main difference from IDispatchMessageInspector / IClientMessageInspector is that it works on lower level, so it captures original byte content including any malformed xml.

In order to implement tracing using this approach you need to wrap a standard [textMessageEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/textmessageencoding) with [custom message encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder) as new [binding element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.textmessageencodingbindingelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and apply that custom binding to endpoint in your [config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-binding-transport-and-encoding).

Also you can see as example how I did it in my project -
[wrapping](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingBindingElement.cs) textMessageEncoding, logging [encoder](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingEncoder.cs), custom binding [element](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingExtensionElement.cs) and [config](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/UsageExamples/ExampleBeta/Client/App.config).

Comment: That sounds cool - can you provide some simple examples instead of links to 600 pages of documentation?