# How do I log SOAP requests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wcf, soap

As most of us already know, in Visual Studio 2017, you can add a `Connected Service` and configure it to point to the SOAP service you'd like, using the relevant WSDL. That creates a set of proxy classes in a `Reference.cs` file that are used to interface with the SOAP service in question.

Is there a way to intercept the converted SOAP at some point in the
    process - programmatically - so we can know what exactly is being
    sent to the target service? I ask this because I need to be able to log the actual SOAP that's being sent out, so using a separate application such as Fiddler is not an option.

I have pored through the code in the `Reference.cs` file and everything is so abstracted away that I can't tell where the conversion actually happens.

For the sake of this discussion, I am using a very simple free SOAP service located at: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx

The contents of the generated `Reference.cs` file are shown at the end of this post. In that code, you can see that the client class's method `AddAsync(...)`, for example, calls `base.Channel.AddAsync(intA, intB)`, a method which is defined in the `CalculatorSoap` interface. So, if `Channel` is a `CalculatorSoap` interface, where is the concrete class that is actually being used? This is an example of what I mean by the prevalence of so much abstraction.

I'll be happy (and grateful) to hear any ideas from any of you regarding what is happening under the hood here.

Thank you.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     //
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace CalculatorSoapServiceReference
{


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "1.0.0.1")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="CalculatorSoapServiceReference.CalculatorSoap")]
    public interface CalculatorSoap
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/Add", ReplyAction="*")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> AddAsync(int intA, int intB);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/Subtract", ReplyAction="*")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> SubtractAsync(int intA, int intB);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/Multiply", ReplyAction="*")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> MultiplyAsync(int intA, int intB);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/Divide", ReplyAction="*")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> DivideAsync(int intA, int intB);
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "1.0.0.1")]
    public interface CalculatorSoapChannel : CalculatorSoapServiceReference.CalculatorSoap, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
    {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "1.0.0.1")]
    public partial class CalculatorSoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<CalculatorSoapServiceReference.CalculatorSoap>, CalculatorSoapServiceReference.CalculatorSoap
    {

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
    /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
    static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

        public CalculatorSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) : 
                base(CalculatorSoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), CalculatorSoapClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public CalculatorSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(CalculatorSoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(remoteAddress))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public CalculatorSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(CalculatorSoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), remoteAddress)
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public CalculatorSoapClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> AddAsync(int intA, int intB)
        {
            return base.Channel.AddAsync(intA, intB);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> SubtractAsync(int intA, int intB)
        {
            return base.Channel.SubtractAsync(intA, intB);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> MultiplyAsync(int intA, int intB)
        {
            return base.Channel.MultiplyAsync(intA, intB);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> DivideAsync(int intA, int intB)
        {
            return base.Channel.DivideAsync(intA, intB);
        }

        public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenAsync()
        {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginOpen(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndOpen));
        }

        public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task CloseAsync()
        {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginClose(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndClose));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.CalculatorSoap))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                return result;
            }
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.CalculatorSoap12))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();
                System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                textBindingElement.MessageVersion = System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.CreateVersion(System.ServiceModel.EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressingVersion.None);
                result.Elements.Add(textBindingElement);
                System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement httpBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement();
                httpBindingElement.AllowCookies = true;
                httpBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                httpBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.Elements.Add(httpBindingElement);
                return result;
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.CalculatorSoap))
            {
                return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx");
            }
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.CalculatorSoap12))
            {
                return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx");
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }

        public enum EndpointConfiguration
        {

            CalculatorSoap,

            CalculatorSoap12,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For #3, just load up Telerik Fiddler and observe the traffic.

Comment: I don't really understand your first two questions.  #1: prior to being put on the wire, #2: Yes, there is some Microsoft code in the framework that does this.  Are you really that interested in how the sausage is made?

Comment: Thanks, Robert.

Here's the thing...I need to be able to grab the SOAP for logging purposes. Using a monitoring application, such as Fiddler, is not an option. I need to do this in code.

And, yes, in this case, I suppose I do need to know how the sausage is made because I need to utilize some of the ingredients.  :)

Comment: SOAP is just XML, so it's just a "XML deserialisation".

Comment: Yeah, it's more or less RPC (Remote Procedure Call).

Comment: @DavidG : Understood. But where is that conversion from a C# class to SOAP/XML taking place?

Comment: Inside the framework somewhere, why do you care?

Comment: `Here's the thing...I need to be able to grab the SOAP for logging purposes. Using a monitoring application, such as Fiddler, is not an option. I need to do this in code.` -- Then that's the question you should be asking in your post.

Comment: @DavidG: Because, as I mentioned above, I need to programmatically grab the SOAP and send it to a log. This is for auditing purposes.

Comment: Edit your question to focus specifically on the programmatic logging.  We can't give you a complete rundown of WCF internals, but we *can* tell you how to log it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : I just updated my post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7172481/102937

Comment: Thank you, @RobertHarvey. I'm looking at that post now to see if I can use it in my case.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question number 3, you can use the Message Inspector extension. There are [details here on how to set it up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors)

With the message inspector you can view, persist, manipulate the SOAP message on out going requests, incoming replies, incoming requests, and outgoing replies.

Also regarding the inner workings WCF uses the Message object for processing SOAP envelopes. You can read more [about that here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-message-class)

The message is part of the Channel Model, there is quite a [bit of info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/channel-model-overview)

Comment: Much thanks to both Robert Harvey and Popo for your help on this. The MessageInspector approach was exactly what I needed. That allows me to intercept SOAP for both requests and responses. Perfect! Thanks again.